# MVC 5 - Order by MAX() using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, max

I have an IQueryable LINQ statement that is returning the top 5 latest reports that have been viewed. I currently have the LINQ statement returning the correct list, but I don't want to see duplicate reports if someone viewed them more than once. I believe I need to use the MAX() syntax, but i'm failing to understand where to put it in my LINQ statement. I have been searching online, but I don't feel like I have came across any solution that makes sense to me.

The top 10 records in the database look like this:

**Report_Num**

---

20
20
20
12
12
5
5
5
7
4

When my LINQ statement runs, it's returning this:

**Report_Num**

---

20
20
20
12
12

But I'm trying to get it to return this:

**Report_Num**

---

20
12
5
7
4

```
var QuickLinks = (System.Linq.IQueryable<WebReportingToolDAL.Models.ViewModels.QuickLinksViewModel>)null;
            var sso = b.getSSO(User.Identity.Name);

        QuickLinks = (from r in db.Report_Completion_Status
                      join ru in db.Report_Web_Usage
                      on r.Report_Num equals ru.report_num
                      where ru.sso == sso
                      select new WebReportingToolDAL.Models.ViewModels.QuickLinksViewModel
                      {
                          report_name = r.Report_Name,
                          report_link = r.Report_Link,
                          report_num = r.Report_Num,
                          hit_date = ru.hit_date.Value
                      }).OrderByDescending(x => x.hit_date).Take(5);
```

Comment: Looks like you might have to use Distinct?

Comment: are you looking to get the most recent hit date?

Comment: Thank you for the quick respnoses. @NetMage seemed to answer my question. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by r so you can find the maximum `hit_date.Value` for each group:

```
var QuickLinks = (from r in db.Report_Completion_Status
              join ru in db.Report_Web_Usage
              on r.Report_Num equals ru.report_num
              where ru.sso == sso
              group ru by new { r.Report_Name, r.Report_Link, r.Report_Num } into rug
              select new WebReportingToolDAL.Models.ViewModels.QuickLinksViewModel {
                  report_name = rug.Key.Report_Name,
                  report_link = rug.Key.Report_Link,
                  report_num = rug.Key.Report_Num,
                  hit_date = rug.Max(ru => ru.hit_date.Value)
              }).OrderByDescending(x => x.hit_date).Take(5);
```

Comment: NetMage - that was it! Thank you!!